# Iteratively create layers of json

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, nodes

I have several arrays of strings that I want to generate a object out of. An example is this. Given I have:

```js
let graph = {}
let a = ["Vehicle", "Car", "Sport"]
let b = ["Vehicle", "Car", "Van"]
let c = ["Vehicle", "Truck", "4x4"]
```

I want to make a function that I can pass a into and it would update graph to be:

```
{
    name: "Vehicle",
    children: [
        {
            name: "Car",
            children: [
                "Sport"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I then pass `b` into the function and graph sees that "Vehicle" > "Car" already exists so it just pushes "Van" into the children. Then when `c` is passed it pushes a child onto the Vehicle children. I am having trouble as with a loop I am not able to account for the fact that the input can be of any length (not just 3). How can I loop through the depth of an object like this?

Comment: I see posts like this about once a week. That pattern is to write a recursive function which takes in a list and the 'current location' in the graph, then recursively iterate down the list. Do that for each piece of data (a, b, c) and customize for your specific structure

Comment: for(let val in obj)

Comment: FYI this is called a tree (or "forest" if there are multiple roots), which might help with searching.

Comment: This is not valid tree, Why 3rd nested node contain just array ? `children[0].children = [ "Sport" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments box that, Your expected result isn't valid node tree, Because 3rd nested node should not contain array.

Anyway Here is my answer:

```js
const nodes = new Map([["graph", { children: [], name: 'graph' }]]); // 'graph' is the root node 
const entries = [["Vehicle", "Car", "Sport"], ["Vehicle", "Car", "Van"], ["Vehicle", "Truck", "4x4"]];

function* createNodeIds(entrie, parentId, deep = 0) {
    const name = entrie.shift();
    const nodeId = parentId + '.' + name;
    yield [parentId, nodeId, name, ++deep];
    while (entrie.length)
        yield* createNodeIds(entrie, nodeId, deep);
}

for (const entrie of entries)
    for (const [parentId, nodeId, name, deep] of createNodeIds(entrie, 'graph'))
        if (!nodes.has(nodeId)) {
            const node = { name, children: [] }
            nodes.set(nodeId, node);
            nodes.get(parentId).children.push(deep > 2 ? name : node)
        }

console.log(nodes.get('graph.Vehicle'));
```